# ng-repeat with ng-click not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i got some new issues in my spa with angularjs.

THIS ist my HTML:

```html
<a ng-repeat="friend in chat.friendlist" ng-click="loadChat('{{friend.friend_username}}')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chat" data-dismiss="modal"  class="list-group-item p-x-md">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle text-success text-xs m-r-xs"></i>
                    <span>{{friend.friend_username}} - {{friend.gamename}}</span>
                </a>
```

This is my controller:

```
"use strict";

    app.controller("chatCtrl", ["userService", "socket" , "chatService", "$scope", function (userService, socket , chatService, $scope) {
        var self = this;

        self.friendlist = chatService.friendlist;

        chatService.init(userService.username);

        $scope.loadChat = function (username) {
            console.log(username); //console logs {{friend.friend_username}}
            chatService.chatWith(username);
        }

    }]);
```

Everything is working properly except the username within the loadChat function.
The username console logs {{friend.friend_username}} and not the value of friend.friend_username as i want to do. Within the DOM everything looks fine. ng-click="loadChat('USERNAME')" is shown properly but in chat controller the username is set as {{friend.friend_username}}. I´ve no clue why this happens. I hope someone can help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly pass the user name to `ngClick`, Don't use string interpolation

```
<a ng-click="loadChat(friend.friend_username)" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need interpolation

```
ng-click="loadChat(friend.friend_username)"
```